# jGIT Track File Location Change

Tags: git, jgit

A GIT file location may change through GIT PULL or change of the branches.
How can I track the file position change?
I am using jGIT, an Eclipse library for GIT.
Currently I do:

```
final PullCommand pullCommand = git.pull().setRemote("origin").setRemoteBranchName(git.getRepository().getBranch());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is worth to keep in mind, that Git (and thus JGit) tracks content, not files. When a file is moved or renamed, Git just sees that a file was added with the new name, and a file was deleted with the old name.

With `DiffFormatter::scan` a list of files that have been changed between two states of a repository (e.g. two commits, or a commit and the work dir) can be obtained. The method returns a list of `DiffEntry`s, each describing an added, deleted, or modified file.

The `DiffFormatter` may be configured with a `FollowFilter` or `setDetectRenames(true)` to use heuristics to detect renames. See the resulting `DiffEntry`'s `changeType` or compare `oldPath` and `newPath`.

If you intend to track changes to the working directory, you may consider using a file watcher instead. This would also include changes made outside of your application.